# Web Requests Run Differently on Different Computers

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, web, webclient

I have two desktop computers running Windows 7

I have tried the same program and it will run on one computer, but the other throws an exception: "**The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly**"

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        Try
            MsgBox(New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=12345"))
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem seems to be only with *wunderground.com*.

What gives?

BTW, using `WebRequest` to fetch the webpage produced the same results.

Comment: Could there be different network / firewall settings?

Comment: I forgot to mention, the problem is only with _wunderground.com_ site.

Comment: If you log on to the computer that fails to send the request and open a browser trying to navigate to wunderground.com do you succeed?

Comment: Yes, a browser will open it.